# How do I download a file using SVN+ssh link?

Tags: ssh, svn

I am trying to download the file from the link list `svn+ssh://svn@myhost.com/myfile`.
I have setup private key on my PC, and public key is on the remote server.when I execute the above  link command i can see the files on the server like file1/, file2/, etc.

What do I need to execute to get the server files on my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://svn@myhost.com/myfile
```

Comment: Thanks Braiam you are correct.i tried the link and Voila download started.